# popover like effect on div

Tags: html, css, angularjs, popover

I have a div and I want to show it on bottom of click of another div just like the popover but with position relative to my first set of divs..

I am using angular to loop through the divs.I am trying the following code but doesnt seem to be working.. Is there any way using jquery or css tweaking i can achieve this?

*EDIT -  The output needed is  like in a row i"ll display say 3 options, in next row another 3. If i click on any option . The hidden div should appear just below the option I clicked and in between first and second row.

My code

```js
My Controller code: -


  app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.options = [{
        name: 'First Option',
        value: '1st answer'
      }, {
        name: 'Second Option',
        value: '2nd answer'
      }, {
        name: 'Third Option',
        value: '3rd answer'
      }, {
        name: 'Fourth option',
        value: '4th answer'
      }];

    }
  ]);
```

```css
.btn-option {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.change-answer {
  width: 30%;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color=#f6f6f6;
  border 1px solid #DDD;
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
I have a div and I want to show it on bottom of click of another div. I am using angular to loop through the divs. My HTML code

<div class="clearfix">
  <div ng-repeat="option in options">
    <div class="btn-options">
      {{option.name}}
    </div>
    <button class="change-answer">Show Me just below the option on clicking any of the option.{{option.value}}
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: inside the hidden element add `ng-show="showMe"` and the element you click to show it `ng-click="showMe = !showMe"`

Comment: Thanx  Tj Gienger.... Actually on opening of the hidden div  the alignment of the first div is distorted...     I wanted the output like in a row i"ll display say 3 options in next row another 3. If i click on any option . The hidden div should appear just below the option I clicked and tin between first and second row.